# How to find out which user a given Azure DevOps token (PAT) belongs to?

Tags: azure-devops, token

Occasionally we encounter an Azure DevOps pipeline or piece of code using a token nobody knows where it came from. This should not happen, of course, but by times reality differs from an ideal world.

If I only have an Azure DevOps "Personal Access Token", how can I find out which user it belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am afraid you can't find out which user a PAT belongs to.

The PAT(personal access token) will not be exposed anywhere after you create it, it will just be stored in the database on Microsoft side.

Also, you could not get the related information via the personal access token itself, at most you can use the REST API - [Pats - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get the PAT related information(e.g. displayname, targetAccounts, etc) via the `authorizationId`, but if you just have the token itself, you could not fetch the `authorizationId` firstly.

Comment: It would also be a security risk if you could find out to whom the PAT belongs to. Because then you would know if it is an admin or not and could use the information to do things (like getting all Orgs of the user and then do stuff in those orgs).

Comment: No, @SebastianSchütze, that is not a security risk. For one thing, if a bad actor has your PAT, your security is already compromised. Secondly, PATs are scoped (limited) to certain functionality, and cannot be used to do *anything* that the user who created it can do.

Comment: No agreeing. Information is an attack surface. Yes the secret is possibly compromised but having only the secret does not tell you where it exactly came from. An additional argument just using logic: I have never seen any vendor offering the possibility to find out the user by giving the secret to an API. Now the question: Why would you not see that anywhere?

Having a password without knowing the user does not help you and that is good. What e.g. Azure DevOps does is revoking the token when you commit it to Github. But that is the provider of the secret.

Answer (score 5):

As Okan mentioned this does work and will return the [ConnectionData (interface docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/connectiondata#properties) which includes the authenticated and authorized user details.

---

`curl --user :{PAT} https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/connectionData | jq`

In the command above curl is being used to make the request and the output is being provided to the `jq` command using the `|` symbol to format the output.

The `-u` flag in Okans original answer is short for the [`--user` flag](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) and is used to provide the user and password in the format of `user:password`.

In this instance user isn't required and so only `:{PAT}` is required

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas so let me share mine as well; first, it's not a code, it's a command that you can run on your terminal. SO is not a source of truth or document store that you can consume for further learning. Many developers tend to solve their problems as quickly as possible, so if anyone does not familiar with a topic, they can directly ask for a reference for further reading. And lastly, anyone on that platform is free to contribute in their way, the community will adjust the quality of contribution via upvote/downvote functionalities.